# Bug with opening custom tabs

Tags: bug, new-nav

I think I found a bug with the new tab set up.

When I go to click on one off my tabs sometimes the menus for the other tabs get stuck open. For example, here I am trying to get to my "IAP' tab:

[image]

When I click on it, and then mouse over the other tabs, it opens them and prevents me from closing them without having to click each one twice.

**This is effecting the Safari browser. It happens consistently on it. I am unable to reproduce the issue on Chrome.**

Comment: I click on the arrow next to the tab and then without clicking, I mouse over the other tabs. It happens consistently.

Comment: The all mighty Safari

Comment: Can't repro in Chrome...

Comment: Can't reproduce in Chrome either. Edited post.